# Vertical Stacking like GTK in Java Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, layout

I want to stack `JComponent`s vertically, similar to a `JList`, but since the amount of items is very low and I want a highly custom interface - I wanted to try a vertically stacked set of components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A vertical [`BoxLayout`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) should be easiest.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) manager and tweak the `GridBagConstraints` properties (gridy and gridx attributes) to achieve the needed result.

Answer (score 1):

`BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS), GridLayout(0, 1)`, and if really needed `GridBagLayout`